# Web scrape to get news release from website playwright

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, playwright

I need to scrape from this website  http://www.pbc.gov.cn/en

All news release by central bank of China.

The structure of news is that all news reside into this :
http://www.pbc.gov.cn/en/3688110/3688172/4756445/index.html

This a one example of news: http://www.pbc.gov.cn/en/3688110/3688172/4756445/5007742/index.html

This is a html part of it:

```
<div class="prhhd1"> 
   <a href="/en/3688110/3688172/4756445/5007742/index.html" class="ListL" style="display: none;"></a> 
   <div class="ListR NoImg"> 
    <span class="prhhdata">2023-08-01</span> 
    <a href="/en/3688110/3688172/4756445/5007742/index.html" onclick="void(0)" target="_blank" title="PBOC and BOM Renews Bilateral Currency Swap Agreement">PBOC and BOM Renews Bilateral Currency Swap Agreement</a> 
   </div> 
  </div>
```

From this url
http://www.pbc.gov.cn/en/3688110/3688172/4756445/4995614/index.html

We get this tag:

```
<div class="prhhd1"> 
   <a href="/en/3688110/3688172/4756445/4995614/index.html" class="ListL" style="display: none;"></a> 
   <div class="ListR NoImg"> 
    <span class="prhhdata">2023-07-23</span> 
    <a href="/en/3688110/3688172/4756445/4995614/index.html" onclick="void(0)" target="_blank" title="Pan Gongsheng Attends the Twelfth Tripartite Governors" meeting'="">Pan Gongsheng Attends the Twelfth Tripartite Governors' Meeting</a> 
   </div> 
  </div>
```

I need to get the last 10 news release by their title and and news content.

Desired output for http://www.pbc.gov.cn/en/3688110/3688172/4756445/4995614/index.html

is:

Pan Gongsheng Attends the Twelfth Tripartite Governors' Meeting

The Twelfth Tripartite Governors' Meeting among the People's Bank of China (PBOC), the Bank of Japan (BOJ),
and the Bank of Korea (BOK) was held in Yokohama, Japan on July 23, 2023. The meeting, which was held for the first time
after four years, was chaired by Governor RHEE Changyong of the BOK. Head of the PBC PAN Gongsheng and Governor UEDA Kazuo of the BOJ also attended.
They exchanged views on recent economic and financial developments. The Thirteenth Tripartite Governors' Meeting will be hosted by PBC in 2024.

I am using this code without success. What I am doing wrong? Any suggestions are welcome.

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scrape_pbc_news(url):
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch()
        context = browser.new_context()
        page = context.new_page()

        page.goto(url)
        page.wait_for_selector('.prhhd1')
        news_elements = page.query_selector_all('.prhhd1')[:10]

        for news_element in news_elements:
            title_element = news_element.query_selector('a[title]')
            if not title_element:
                print("Title element not found.")
                continue

            title = title_element.inner_text()

            news_link = title_element.get_attribute('href')
            print(f"Scraping news from: http://www.pbc.gov.cn{news_link}")
            news_page_url = f"http://www.pbc.gov.cn{news_link}"
            page.goto(news_page_url)

            # Wait for the content element to be visible
            page.wait_for_selector('.contxt')

            news_page_content = page.content()

            soup = BeautifulSoup(news_page_content, 'html.parser')
            content_element = soup.select_one('.contxt')

            if not content_element:
                print("Content element not found.")
                continue

            content = content_element.get_text().strip()

            print(title)
            print(content)
            print("--------------")

        browser.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "http://www.pbc.gov.cn/en/3688110/3688172/4756445/index.html"
    scrape_pbc_news(url)
```